# iOS5 - manual Storyboard view selection in code

Tags: ios5, storyboard

I am new to iOS and using storyboards for the first time.  When my app starts it checks back with the a server app I have written to see if the saved credentials are authenticated and I then in my AppDelegate class I then attempt to show the appropriate scene in the app's storyboard - MainMenu if authenticated or a Login Screen if not authenticated.

I have tried using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier on the storyboard and also the performSegueWithIdentifier on the initial NavigationController which is set to be the "Initial View Controller" to display the appropriate view..

However with both methods only the blank navigation bar shows and I am unsure where to go from here.

If there was some example code on how others manually manipulate storyboard scenes and viewcontrollers that would be great.  Am I maybe putting the code in the wrong place (ie should it go into the first View Controller) or should that not matter?  No exceptions are raised and I seem to have access to instantiated objects as required.

I am thinking I need to understand the operation of the app delegate's window more, or maybe should I focus on manually loading the storyboard by removing it's reference from the InfoPlist settings?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From my (admittedly haphazard) understanding of storyboards (at the moment), you should have two named segues going from a first viewcontroller, and then you can simply trigger one or the other as need be (I presume there's some sort of "loading/authenticating" screen, however brief?)

```
if (success) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MainMenuSegue" sender: self];   
} else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"LoginSegue" sender: self];  
}
```

To debug, I'd set up buttons on the initial viewcontroller just to be sure the segue linkings/etc are proper.

You really shouldn't need to instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier unless you're working around segue/storyboard limitations. *I think*.

I've put the performSegueWithIdentifier in my app's first viewcontroller's viewDidAppear (not the best idea, I think; but that's sort of the soonest it should happen? and I would hedge towards saying it should be triggered somewhere in the viewcontroller stack, not from the appdelegate, but I haven't tested that).

Comment: performSegueWithIdentifier: is an instance method of UIViewController. AppDelegate does not extend this class...

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't call the instance method on the UIViewController from the AppDelegate.... But I really should extend my answer above. Lost track of it. :)

Comment: Hmm. If you wanted no animation, that might require a "custom" segue, where you then assign a Segue Class to the segue that basically does no animation. [I found an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260947/ios-custom-segue-between-two-viewcontrollers-in-landscape-mode)